# How do you make Service Fabric explorer use HTTPS on a Local service fabric cluster?

Tags: appfabric

We are self-hosting a service fabric cluster on our infrastructure. We have a certificate (not self-signed) that can be used on our servers. We have this certificate loaded into the cluster manifest in the security section as:

```
"CertificateInformation": {
  "reverseProxyCertificateCommonNames": {
    "CommonNames": [
      {
        "certificateCommonName": "*.domain.com"
      }
    ],
    "X509StoreName": "My"
  }
}
```

We use this certificate for our applications hosted inside the service fabric cluster and everything works great.

However, if I try to hit the service fabric explorer (http://cluster.domain.com:19080/Explorer/index.html) I can only access that via http and not https. How do I make this use https instead?